# SQL Insert into Select failure due to one of the set of records

Tags: sql-server, insert

I am trying to insert a set of records into a table using

```
Insert into tbl1 Select * from tbl
```

One of the records failed due to check constrain in tbl1. But i want to insert the other records which have passed the check constraint and others i want to catch them as exception. Could someone please help.

Comment: First of all: I would recommend to **explicitly define** the columns, both in your `INSERT` statement, as well as your `SELECT` statement. Just to be safe - just to know what column gets inserted into which other column.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you need to be more selective about your `SELECT` - exclude those rows that are trouble from your selection:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl1(Col1, Col2, ...., ColN)
   SELECT Col1, Col2, ....., ColN
   FROM dbo.tbl
   WHERE (some condition here to exclude those rows that don't match the `CHECK` constraint.....)
```